# Wordpress Embedded Videos in Post versus Template

Tags: wordpress, templates, video, post, rss

I've tried creating a post with a video embedded into the post (e.g. html instead of visual), and at the same time also insert an embed code into the template (e.g. single.php) The source view of those two code look identical in format, two videos are both visible on the page, yet only one video shows in RSS feed. The one that's embedded into the post.

Anyone knows why this is happening? I want my video to be called using a function, and still work in RSS, but I don't think I can do that unless... I know the differences? At least maybe I'll know what other operation I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're embedding the video in single.php, you may have put it outside of the loop, ie. outside of

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

(more of the loop)

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

and as result not showing up in RSS.

If it's in the post via the post editor, it's inside the loop and available as RSS as a single  post.

If you need to execute php in a post/page, there are plugins for that.

Comment: I did a recheck on that, my embed code is indeed inside the loop.

Here's what I found out from my research, wordpress wrap the post content with the enclosure function, and not outside post. Correct me if I'm wrong.

However I'm still pretty unsure which and how do I use the existing function to wrap my embed code with the enclosure tag. Any idea?